# How to clone element with given class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, clone

I am using `getElementById` when I need to clone the div element.

Code:

```
printHTML( document.getElementById("div_name").cloneNode(true));
```

Now I need to use `getElementsByClassName`

CloneNode is not working when using `getElementsByClassName`. 
How can I put class name in here?

Thank's

EDIT:

When I try to use this:

```
printHTML( $('.dataTables_scroll').clone(true) );
```

You can see my function:

```
function printHTML(clonedDive){
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.contentWindow.onunload = function(){
        $(".DTTT_container").show("fast");
        $("#header_outer").show("fast");
        $(".ColVis.TableTools").show("fast");
        $("#footer").show("fast");
     };
      iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(clonedDive);
      iframe.contentWindow.print();

      document.body.removeChild(iframe); 
}
```

I am getting an error in this line:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(clonedDive);
```

This is an error description:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as jQuery when you're using getElement...?  The jQuery solution for this is easy, but doesn't use those functions.

Comment: why have you tagged `jquery` when you're using - and asking us to use - the native DOM methods?

Comment: Since you're already including jQuery in your project I would recommend using jQuery to get the elements by class name since the native `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in IE until version 9:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#fivemethods

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` gets a nodelist, or an array-like object containing elements if you will, as there can be more than one element with the same class.

`getElementsByClassName` does this even if only one element matches the class.
You can generally recognize methods like that be the `s` in `getElements`, which means it gets multiple elements, i.e. a nodeList.

`getElementById` only gets one element as ID's are unique.

To get the first element in the nodelist, use bracket notation, like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("div_name")[0].cloneNode(true);
```

or one could use `querySelector`, which gets the first matching element only

```
document.querySelector(".div_name").cloneNode(true);
```

The jQuery solution would be:

```
$('.div_name').clone(true);
```

and to iterate over elements with a certain classname you'd use a loop

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("div_name");

for ( var i=0; i<elems.length; i++ ) {
    printHTML( elems[i].cloneNode(true) );
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error in this line: `iframe.appendChild(clonedDive);`

Comment: I removed my edit, as what you are doing seems to work for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Krqtg/)

Answer (score 2):

Due to *getElementsByClassName* returns an object's array, so you have to use for loop to iterates among them, as follows:

```
 for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("div_name").length; i++){  

printHTML( document.getElementsByClassName("div_name")[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```

otherwise, if you know the index of the element you have let we say 1

```
printHTML( document.getElementsByClassName("div_name")[1].cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: It is a loop now, but you don't really **have** to use a loop! If there's only one element, or when targeting an element with a certain index, a loop is unneccessary.

Comment: @adeneo it's useless to use `getElementsByClassName` if you're targeting a single element. That's probably why @sємsєм assumed `document.getElementsByClassName("div_name")` would return an array.

When targeting a single element, it's faster to give that element an ID and use `getElementById`

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen - You did'nt get it, you can target one single element with JS even if the page contains several elements with that same class, and then a loop would'nt do much good. getElementsByClassName always returns a nodelist, as do all methods with the "**s**", like getElementsByTagName etc.

Comment: @adeneo I did get it and I do know that you can target a single element even though you're using a method that starts with `getElement**s**`. 

But I'm talking about speed and best practice. If you're targeting a single element with `getElementsByClassName`, Javascript is iterating through all these elements even though you want just one.

Therefore, It's better to use a method that targets a single element _when possible_. Of course, there are situations where this isn't applicable.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen - Agreed, when targeting a single element, ID's are always better, the only point I was making is that you don't **have** to use a for loop, it depends, and using a loop is'nt always neccessary, and it's not really the answer either, but the line above where it says "returns an object's array" is what the question is really all about.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work? :

```
printHTML( document.getElementsByClassName("class_name")[0].cloneNode(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the elements and clone one by one...

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i += 1) {
    // Clone e[i] here
    console.log(e[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```