# explanation of zero index in getElementByTagname method

Tags: javascript

i am trying to use the getElemenstByTagName  method to access certain array elements.i have searched the internet and found some of its uses.i have seen that without a [0] at the end of the tagname this method does not work.say

in my code if i use

```
var c=document.getElementsByTagName("P");
```

it doesn't work.rather i have to use

```
var c=document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0];
```

what does this [0] index means and why it is used??

FULL CODE :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var j=2;
var temp;
var arr=["favourite","fruit","is","mango","orange","apple"];
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
document.body.innerHTML+=arr[i]+" ";
}
setInterval(function (){

j++;

var c=document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0];
c.style.color="blue";

c.innerHTML=arr[j]+" ";
if(j==5){j=2;}

},2000);


</script>
<p style="position:absolute;float:right;top:0px;left:97px;border:0px solid black;width:60px;height:50px;"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914618/how-to-clone-element-with-given-class-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName('tag-name')` returns an array of HTML elements ([HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection))

So `var foo = document.getElementsByTagName('tag-name')` is an `HTMLCollection (can be thought of array of HTML Elements)`

Therefore, `foo[0]` or `document.getElementsByTagName('tag-name')[0]` contains first item in the array, i.e., First element that matches the tagname!

Lean More about `getElementsByTagName()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName

If you have too many elements on your webpage, then you might use the concept of `IDs` to access elements. For example, consider this HTML excerpt

```
<p id="topPara">....</p>
<p id="midPara">....</p>
<p id="bottomPara">....</p>
```

Now to access the individual Elements you would use:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('topPara');
```

which would return the element that has id topPara in `foo`  so that you can now use Methods related to the element like `foo.methodName()`

Comment: +1 for specifying that it's a `HTMLColletion`, so people don't confuse it with an `Array` object.

Comment: thanks!is this method helpful when there are too many elements of same kind in a particular page as i can't get to any desired element directly?

Comment: @user3138436 : Edited the post, so that it may now help you

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple instances of the same tag (and there usually are), so `getElementsByTagName()` returns array of this HTML elements. Actually name of the function is self-explanatory - get **ElementS** ByTagName()

That's why you have to use index - you don't get in return signle HTML element.

If you want to access exactly one particular `<p>`, then give it an `ID` and use `getElementById()';

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName returns you the array of all HTML elements with searched tagname, which in this case you have only one in your page, but it is still listed in array as a first item with idex 0.